# Snap.svg - How Matrix.add() works?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I can't understand mathematically Matrix.add() works, Snap.svg docs says:

> [Adds the given matrix to existing one](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Matrix.add)

HTML:

```
<svg id="svgout" width="1000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 800 800"></svg>
```

JS:

```
var paper = Snap("#svgout"); 
var r = paper.rect(0,0,100,100);

var mat = new Snap.matrix();
mat.scale(.5);
mat.add(mat.scale(3));

r.attr({transform: mat});
console.log(r.getBBox().width + "  " + r.getBBox().height );
```

my problem here:

```
mat.scale(.5);           // width and height = 50
mat.add(mat.scale(3));   // width and height = 300
```

so, final width and height should be 50 + 300 = 350
but the result in console.log = 225

Another try

```
mat.scale(1);           // width and height = 100
mat.add(mat.scale(3));  // width and height = 300
```

my expectation: 100 + 300 = 400
but the result in console = 900 !

this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzwzjK?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
mat.scale(.5)
```

mat is now a scale 0.5 matrix (s0.5)

Then we take the s0.5 matrix and do

```
mat.add(mat.scale(3))
```

so that's

s1.5.add(s1.5)

and 1.5 x 1.5 = 2.25

QED

The other example is the same 3 x 3 = 9